# Criar id pra um novo ListView?

Tags: android, listview

Estou com o seguinte problema, já tenho um listView e quero criar outro, mas está dando o seguinte erro:

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/listView" <----- ***Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@android:id/listView').***
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
```

Comment: remova o prefixo "@android:id/listView" e substitua por "@+id/listView" e tente novamente

Comment: Era isso mesmo, Valeu :)

Comment: Boa! Respondi com a explicação

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando o prefixo `@android:`, indica que você está tentando referenciar a um `resource` diretamente do SDK do android importado em seu projeto.

[Seguindo a documentação:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ResourcesFromXml)

**`@[<nome_do_pacote>:]<tipo_resource>/<nome_resource>`**

**`<nome_do_pacote>`** é o nome do pacote que o resource está alocado. Você não precisa indicar caso o resource seja do mesmo pacote do seu projeto.

**`<tipo_resource>`** é uma subclasse do arquivo `R` do tipo do resuorce

**`<nome_resource>`** ou é o nome do seu resource (sem a extensão) ou o atributo `android:name` do elemento no XML

Ou seja, ao invés de `@android:id/listView`, coloque `@+id/listView` e irá funcionar!

Comment: vc sabe me dizer se variáveis e métodos com o mesmo nome mais em diferentes classe (no mesmo pacote) geram conflito e fazem a aplicação para de executar?

Comment: Se você tiver ID's iguais em XML's e Classes diferentes, não há problema algum! Na verdade, o próprio SDK faz isso. Você irá encontrar vários ID's como `title` por exemplo, mas de arquivos distintos

Comment: Certo, pensei que alguns métodos com o mesmo nome estava fazendo a aplicação parar... você sabe oq pode acarretar uma parada na aplicação?

Comment: Existem vários motivos para isso! Formule uma pergunta colocando o seu stacktrace de erro para que nós possamos te ajudar

Comment: Na verdade não aponta nenhum erro, fiz uma pergunta aqui... Só tem alguns warnings de importações não utilizadas. Só na hora de executar, quando clico sobre o botão que leva ao ListView a aplicação para de executar.